# Build issue with ADCME package in Julia-1.5.3

Tags: python, function, julia, radial

I am trying to use `ACDME.jl` package to perform `radial basis function`.
While building the package it outputs an issue related to tensorflow dependencies with some warnings. I have already installed tensorflow in my Python environment. I have also tried switching the environment to `Conda.jl` but it still throws the same error.

## Error

```
using Pkg
Pkg.build("ADCME")

┌ Error: Error building `ADCME`: 
│ ┌ Warning: Pkg.installed() is deprecated
│ └ @ Pkg C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Pkg.jl:554
│ ┌ Warning: Pkg.installed() is deprecated
│ └ @ Pkg C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Pkg.jl:554
│ [ Info: Your Julia version is 1.5.3, current ADCME version is 0.6.7, ADCME dependencies installation path: C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme
│ [ Info:  --------------- (1/6) Install Tensorflow Dependencies  --------------- 
│ [ Info: ADCME dependencies have already been installed.
│ [ Info:  --------------- (2/6) Check Python Version  --------------- 
│ ┌ Warning: Pkg.installed() is deprecated
│ └ @ Pkg C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Pkg.jl:554
│    Building Conda ─→ `C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\Conda\x5ml4\deps\build.log`
│    Building PyCall → `C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\deps\build.log`
│ ┌ Info: PyCall Python version: C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\python.exe
│ └ Conda Python version: C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\python.exe
│ [ Info:  --------------- (3/6) Looking for TensorFlow Dynamic Libraries --------------- 
│ ERROR: LoadError: PyError (PyImport_ImportModule
│ 
│ The Python package tensorflow could not be imported by pyimport. Usually this means
│ that you did not install tensorflow in the Python version being used by PyCall.
│ 
│ PyCall is currently configured to use the Python version at:
│ 
│ C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\python.exe
│ 
│ and you should use whatever mechanism you usually use (apt-get, pip, conda,
│ etcetera) to install the Python package containing the tensorflow module.
│ 
│ One alternative is to re-configure PyCall to use a different Python
│ version on your system: set ENV["PYTHON"] to the path/name of the python
│ executable you want to use, run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia.
│ 
│ Another alternative is to configure PyCall to use a Julia-specific Python
│ distribution via the Conda.jl package (which installs a private Anaconda
│ Python distribution), which has the advantage that packages can be installed
│ and kept up-to-date via Julia.  As explained in the PyCall documentation,
│ set ENV["PYTHON"]="", run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia. Then,
│ To install the tensorflow module, you can use `pyimport_conda("tensorflow", PKG)`,
│ where PKG is the Anaconda package that contains the module tensorflow,
│ or alternatively you can use the Conda package directly (via
│ `using Conda` followed by `Conda.add` etcetera).
│ 
│ ) <class 'ImportError'>
│ ImportError('\n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Julia 1.5.3\\bin\\julia.exe"\n  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.1"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.\n\nOriginal error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.\n')
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
│     from tensorflow_core import *
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
│     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
│     module = self._load()
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
│     module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
│     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
│     import numpy as np
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
│     from . import core
│   File "C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
│     raise ImportError(msg)
│ 
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] pyimport(::String) at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\src\PyCall.jl:547
│  [2] top-level scope at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\deps\build.jl:77
│  [3] include(::String) at .\client.jl:457
│  [4] top-level scope at none:5
│ in expression starting at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\deps\build.jl:77
└ @ Pkg.Operations C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:949
```

Package reference: https://juliahub.com/docs/ADCME/b8Ld2/0.6.6/rbf/

Questions:

1. How may I resolve this issue?
2. If this is some compatibility issue, then may I know if there is any alternate package which can perform these operation (`radial basis function`)?

## Update

As per suggestions by @Przemyslaw Szufel in the comments, I reinstalled the python and created a virtual environment for Julia. Here I install and build the `ADCME` package. So far I manage to fix the first issue but I encounter new errors as listed below.

```
[ Info: Precompiling ADCME [07b341a0-ce75-57c6-b2de-414ffdc00be5]
WARNING: Method definition size(PyCall.PyObject) in module PyCall at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\src\PyCall.jl:809 overwritten in module ADCME at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\src\variable.jl:214.   
  ** incremental compilation may be fatally broken for this module **

WARNING: Method definition length(PyCall.PyObject) in module PyCall at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\src\PyCall.jl:808 overwritten in module ADCME at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\src\variable.jl:238. 
  ** incremental compilation may be fatally broken for this module **

WARNING: Method definition lastindex(PyCall.PyObject) in module PyCall at deprecated.jl:70 overwritten in module ADCME at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\src\variable.jl:454.
  ** incremental compilation may be fatally broken for this module **

WARNING: Method definition *(PyCall.PyObject, PyCall.PyObject) in module PyCall at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\src\pyoperators.jl:11 overwritten in module ADCME at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\src\ops.jl:102.
  ** incremental compilation may be fatally broken for this module **

┌ Warning: Cannot load C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\deps\CustomOps\build\adcme.dll. Please recompile the shared library by `ADCME.precompile()` for using custom operators.
└ @ ADCME C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\ADCME\hCmEo\src\ADCME.jl:76
```

Please may someone explain the cause of this error and suggest solution to resolve this.

Comment: This looks to be linked with numpy and not TF. Does the numpy package work on your python environment ?

Comment: @pLOPeGG, Thanks for the response, yeah I have numpy-v1.20 already installed in the python environment.

Comment: You could just use Surrogates.jl for RBFs: https://surrogates.sciml.ai/latest/radials/

Comment: It seems to use Python at a strange location C:\Users\user\.julia\adcme\python.exe  I would say that something is messed up with your Python config. Everything needs to be installed in one and the same Python installation. Currently each part of your project is in different python and hence it does not work.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas, Thanks for the suggestion. I will try out the package.
Highly appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, Thanks for the suggestion, as per your comment I tried using this with virtual environment and managed to fix the first issues. However, I encounter new errors, I have updated the question with my findings.
Thanks for your kind help !!!

Comment: When you reatach Python you need to `Pkg.build("PyCall");Pkg.build("WhateverYourPackageIs)` and also your package asks for ``ADCME.precompile()``

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, Thanks for suggesting this, I noticed during rebuild process that some of `PyCall` was mixed with `conda.jl` rather than totally dependent on my virtual environment. Hence, I removed the conda and rebuild the package with the python env and now it works perfectly. 
Amazing !! highly appreciate your help !!!